# Exchange rate conversion

Tags: fx, currency, eurodollars, finance-mathematics

If the EUR/USD exchangerate fell by -0,96%, how much has the USD/EUR exchange rate increased?

According to the below charts the number would be +0,97% (currently) but I cant figure out how these number are related.

[EUR/USD](http://www.ariva.de/euro-dollar-kurs)

[USD/EUR](http://www.ariva.de/usd-eur-us-dollar-euro-kurs)

Please state a formula to convert the percentage change of USD/EUR to the change of EUR/USD.

Comment: Hint: if you discount something's price by 50%, you have to raise the price 100% (of the reduced price) to get it back to the original price. Does that help?

Comment: @barrycarter As stated in the question, I would like to see the formula as answer.

Comment: Hint: -1+1/(1-0.0096) = 0.0097

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked Google Finance and the `EUR/USD = 1.1190`.... for arguments sake lets say it goes up by `0.10` to `1.2190` the percentage change = `1.2190/1.1190-1 = +8.94%`

in terms of `USD/EUR` the beginning quote would be `1/1.1190 = 0.8937` but would be `1/1.2190 = 0.8203` after the `EUR/USD` went up by `0.10`. Therefore the change in terms of `USD/EUR = 0.8203/0.8937-1 = -8.21%`

@AlexC formula explains it best:

`1/(1-0.0821)-1= +8.94%` or `1/(1+0.0894)-1= -8.21%`